# slide down height like accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Guys i am working on a div which shows a calender by onclick().
I used toggle method to show and this that calender.

But while scrolling down i want to make the height of the div to change like this [accordion](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlexibleSlideToTopAccordion/).

I want to move my div a little above so that the calender will be visible to the user.
Any ideas  to animate the height which is used in that accordion?

Check this

[http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/VVP3v/2/]

I like to move the calender when i click "Show me the calender"

Comment: Did you tried anything & searching anything yet ?

Comment: Wait, didn't you link us to a *tutorial*?

Comment: Check this fiddle guys http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/VVP3v/               I like to move my screen to the position of calender

Comment: your fiddle is not working....please check

Comment: @bipen check when you click the show me the calender the height changes and the calender appears at the bottom

Comment: ok got it... :).... posted the answer... check if that is what u want... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#calender').position().top }, 'slow');
```

here is the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/VVP3v/5/

you are using slide toggle... so the effect might not look as it is in live.. :)

Comment: Its a tiny div i wanted to show you that when we click the button  the screen should move to the content area not to change height

Comment: I changed my fiddle with a button so that i will easily understandable http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/VVP3v/2/  In this when we click the button  we should move to the calender area.  Calender must be in its position the screen height must be changed similar to that accordion i added

Comment: Hmmm not this but we have to change the height of the screen to go to the position of calender.. Like animate()

Comment: sorry was away.. i think u are asking for this... updated the answer .. please check....:):)..